# Assembly.GetTypes()

Tags: c#, types, .net-2.0, .net-assembly

I have this in my code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);
//dllFile has the correct value of a path of a .dll file
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {...}
```

When I debug my program, everything works fine. When I create the exe for my program, the code comes to assembly.GetTypes() and stops executing. What could cause assembly.GetTypes() to work differently when I'm debugging from when I'm using the exe?

Comment: take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3bdaf65c-520c-4a1a-a825-fc2ca2957bf3/

Comment: Well whatz the path in either case?

Comment: Show please the exact value of dllFile, if you hardcoded it this will not work if you deploy application because in debug mode the exe file in the Debug folder in release in Release folder

Comment: @V4Vendetta The path is correct in both cases:
C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins\S_Ajde.dll

The dll file is loaded just like it should be. The error is in assembly.GetTypes()

Comment: @Serghei The path of the dll file is hardcoded, because the dllFile isn't in bin or debug. It's in C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins\S_Ajde.dll

Comment: You should call `GetExportedTypes()`.

Comment: @leppie The same thing happens.

Comment: That was a comment, not an answer...

Comment: @Prisoner That was it! Can you answer the question pls, so I can choose your answer as the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3bdaf65c-520c-4a1a-a825-fc2ca2957bf3/

> You should never use Assembly.LoadFile().  Use LoadFrom() if you know
>   where the assembly is located, use Load() to let .NET figure out where
>   the assembly is located.  Using Load() should be your preference but
>   may require a .config file to help .NET find the assembly

credit to [@HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

Comment: I should have used Assembly.LoadFrom() instead of Assembly.LoadFile()

Answer (score 1):

When you create an exe file, you have to make sure that your assemblies are in the correct folder and also that the exe file has access to the folder.

Comment: The assemblies are in the correct folder. They are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to that event and do a simple `Assembly.LoadFrom` from a location known to you or even do some fancy loading of your own based on some system you engineer.  There are also `TypeResolve` and `ResourceResolve` events in the `AppDomain` that let you handle those aspects of resolving the various dependencies of an `AppDomain`. For details see this [Microsoft forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/2f49fe59-c1ed-4047-905a-25ac5f396297).